# Running jar inside target folder vs running jar inside project folder

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have weird problem. When I'm running jar from project folder which goes:

java -jar ./target/project.jar

everything works fine, path is read correctly.

```
1107 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean - JMXAgent enabled: CamelJMXAgent[usePlatformMBeanServer=true, createConnector=true, registryPort=10098, serviceUrlPath=/, statisticsLevel=All, onlyRegisterProcessorWithCustomId=false, registerAlways=true, registerNewRoutes=true, mask=false]
2657 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter - Loaded 179 type converters
2853 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: data-feed-camel) is starting
2853 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.management.ManagedManagementStrategy - JMX is enabled
3078 [Camel Thread #1 - Camel Thread #0 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://pjanik-pc:10098/] INFO org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - JMX Connector thread started and listening at: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://pjanik-pc:10098/f

3089 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
3107 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Total 0 routes, of which 0 is started.
3128 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: data-feed-camel) started in 0.255 seconds


org.apache.camel.component.file.FileEndpoint - Endpoint is configured with noop=true so forcing endpoint to be idempotent as well
    59471 [RMI TCP Connection(5)-10.88.55.167] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Route: flt_data_for_0543 started and consuming from: Endpoint[file://src/main/resources/view/flight/following/default/3648/flt_data?idempotentRepository=%23repo-flt_data_for_0543&noop=true&readLock=none]
    60552 [Camel (data-feed-camel) thread #4 -
```

but when I run jar inside target folder

```
1149 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean - JMXAgent enabled: CamelJMXAgent[usePlatformMBeanServer=true, createConnector=true, registryPort=10098, serviceUrlPath=/, statisticsLevel=All, onlyRegisterProcessorWithCustomId=false, registerAlways=true, registerNewRoutes=true, mask=false]
2688 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter - Loaded 179 type converters
2796 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: data-feed-camel) is starting
2796 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.management.ManagedManagementStrategy - JMX is enabled
2975 [Camel Thread #1 - Camel Thread #0 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://pjanik-pc:10098/] INFO org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - JMX Connector thread started and listening at: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://pjanik-pc:10098/
2981 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2989 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Total 0 routes, of which 0 is started.
2991 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: data-feed-camel) started in 0.194 seconds
21055 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-10.88.55.167] INFO org.apache.camel.component.file.FileEndpoint - Endpoint is configured with noop=true so forcing endpoint to be idempotent as well
21588 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-10.88.55.167] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Route: flt_data_for_0432 started and consuming from: Endpoint[file://src/main/resources/view/flight/following/default/3648/flt_data?idempotentRepository=%23repo-flt_data_for_0432&noop=true&readLock=none]
```

it stucks and nothing is doing further

The path is all the time the same:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_DATA_PATH = "view/flight/following/default/3648/";
```

What can be wrong? How can I avoid such a situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Camel route consumes from endpoint `file://src/main/resources/view/flight/following/default/3648/flt_data` which is given as a **relative** path (in your project I guess). Therefore, it makes a difference when you execute your jar from `target` directory or not. This is because you are reading the file directly from the file system and not from your classpath.

In order to avoid this, there are (at least) 2 approaches:

1. You consider the file as provided data consumed by your application: then pass the path to the file as an argument of your application and pass it to your route, the constants for file names you are currently using then become probably useless.
2. You consider the file as a resource (i.e. sort of immutable data): then you can create an `InputStream` for your resource and read the bytes from it. In your case, you would write something like this:

   ```
    InputStream resourceStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(DEFAULT_FLT_DATA_PATH);
    // Read bytes from resourceStream
   ```

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) for the documentation of `getResourceAsStream`.

If you *have* to use a Camel route, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54631264/2703552) suggests that you can use Camel's [Stream component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/stream-component.html) (it also suggests the above approach using an `InputStream`, but in lesser detail). However, it does not mention how and I don't know either. I would advice to ask for clarification on that answer.

Comment: The difference is that your jar is accessing the file directly on the file system, not in the jar itself. What you are looking for is addressed by this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54617966/camel-read-file-from-classpath-resource

Comment: Well, you'll probably need something like a convention i.e. your routes should always be stored in the same folder, relatively to your working directory (so the directory from which you execute `java`, not the location of your jar).

Comment: Not necessarily, for example if your endpoint is defined as `file://routes/flt_data`, then your jar will always read the file `flt_data` located in sub-directory `routes` of your working directory, independently of where your working directory actually is.

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends about the actual nature of the file you are consuming. If it is indeed a resource i.e. the file contains immutable data, then leave it in `src/main/resources` and follow [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54631264/2703552). On the other hand, if your file contains actually an input for your app, then you may follow my above suggestion.

Comment: From what I understand: "Java API" means using the `InputStream` returned by `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/pl/azimuthit/view/flight/following/default/3648/flt_data")` and directly reading bytes from there in order to feed your processor; "Stream component" means using [this](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/stream-component.html).

Comment: I just edited my answer so that it better matches your question.